# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

I looked at the other answers to problems similar to mine but cant seem to solve this.

Here is the code.

```
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","starwars");
  $conn = mysql_select_db("project", $connection);

        // This code assumes $itemID is set to that of 
   // the item that was just rated. 
   // Get all of the user's rating pairs
   $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT r.itemID, r2.ratingValue - r.ratingValue 
               as rating_difference
               FROM rating r, rating r2
               WHERE r.userID=$userID AND 
                       r2.itemID=$itemID AND 
                       r2.userID=$userID;";

   $db_result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
   echo "The result is {$db_result}";
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($db_result)or die('Cannot Execute:'. mysql_error());
```

The error being displayed is:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\recomender\ratingfiles\class.rating.php on
>   line 177

Line 177 is

```
   $db_result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

And if I echo `$conn` it gives the value of "1" which I thought was equal to true, thus boolean, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `$connection` as the second parameter, not `$conn`.

You assign the result of `mysql_select_db` to $conn, and `mysql_select_db` returns true or false, not a connection resource.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means `$conn` is false, meaning it didnt get setup correctly. You may want to check how you have set that up and ensure the database connection details are correct and the server this is running on can access the database server.

Take a look at the return values on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: I have checked the database connection and that all works fine, and i know that $conn is carrying the value 1, is there anyway it can be losing that value between being set and being used in those few lines?

Comment: Post more code so we can see how youre setting it up, and make sure youre not changing it after it is set up

Answer (score 0):

change first 2 lines to

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","starwars");
mysql_select_db("project", $conn);
```

or, better, just refrain from using connection variable at all

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","starwars");
mysql_select_db("project");
...
$db_result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: That would give warning  - `$conn` is not defined in the second example...

Answer (score -1):

```
$db_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Second argument to `mysql_connect` must have

The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php